# What does "foster dialogue" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Tourism professionals, particularly investors, governed by the regulations laid down by the public authorities, should carry out studies of the impact of their development projects on the environment and natural surroundings; they should also deliver, with the greatest transparency and objectivity, information on their future programmes and their foreseeable repercussions and **foster dialogue on their contents with the populations concerned**; <[Source](http://ethics.unwto.org/en/content/global-code-ethics-tourism-article-5)>

Does *foster* mean *encourage* here? Does it simply mean *they should have dialogue about the aims and details of their plans with the populations concerned*?

Comment: Yes - your guess is quite correct. Note that *to **encourage** X* may sometimes mean little more than *speak in support of X*, whereas *to **foster** X* would usually imply taking a more "proactive" role in support of X (actually *doing* things, rather than just talking about them).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Why did you not write this as an answer?

Comment: @serenesat: Because I might easily be convinced this question could have been answered using a dictionary before consulting ELL. It's not obvious to me why the usage should present any special difficulties - but then again I'm not a non-native speaker, so maybe I just don't have the right perspective.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did not understand what does fostering dialogue mean? how can it be fostered?:( it is a bit vague to me.

Comment: What if any dictionary did you consult? The first definition in [the first result returned](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foster) by Googling **define foster** says *to promote the growth or development of; further; encourage*. With the example usage ***to foster new ideas***.

Comment: @Juya I guess that maybe your confusion is not really about *foster* but about the *dialogue* and which word is related to which other words.

Comment: @Damkerng: *That*, for example, is precisely the kind of thinking that would justify this question (but doesn't come naturally to me as a native speaker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could see there being a little confusion when reading that sentence as to whether 'foster' was being used as a verb or an adjective. Are they fostering dialogue, or delivering "foster dialogue"?

It's being used as a verb, and means pretty much what you guessed.

See [verb definition #2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foster#Verb) at Wiktionary:

> 2. (*transitive*) To cultivate and grow something.
>
> > *Our company fosters an appreciation for the arts.*

So, by fostering dialogue, they would be encouraging others to talk about the contents of their development projects. That seems like a strange way to phrase things. I would have used 'impact' rather than 'content'.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, ***foster*** means *'to promote the growth or development of'* (something, typically something regarded as good).

So your guess is right.

Comment: What are you quoting?